# Disabling BACKSPACE in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have an input field for mobile numbers and i want that inside that input field "+91" should be visible to the user all the time.. means he can not erase it.

So i planned to disable BACKSPACE and DELETE button when the value of INPUT FIELD is equal to +91

The startegy is working fine for me in FIREFOX but its all screwed up in CHROME.

I googled a lot but couldnt find any successfull code for Disabling Backspace in CHROME. :(

Here is my code for FIREFOX

```
<script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
document.onkeypress = function(e)  // FireFox/Others 
    {
    var t=e.target.id;
    var kc=e.keyCode;
    if ((kc == 8 || kc == 46) && t == "phonen" && document.getElementById(t).value=="+91")
    { e.preventDefault();
        return false;}
    else {
                return true

    }
   }
   function sett(e)
   {e.value="+91";}
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest me how can i do the same in CHROME???

Comment: This is madness, it's a seriously crazy hack. Why not just have a seperate text box, make it read-only by any means necessary, that shows `+91` and include it in your logic? I absolutely guarantee there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: @Arran : This javascript check i need to apply because of the guy for whom i am developing the website. He wants this only. And at the server side i have much better constraints.

Comment: @Arran : And i accept that this is MADNESS.. :P but cant do anything about it...

Comment: just fake it... http://jsbin.com/elatot/1/

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER: what sort of stupid client would specifically ask for such an arcane requirement?

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER Verious solutions have been offered to you by now, any of them satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in a comment... Don't even bother with this kind of approach. Just fake it. Here's a simple way (though you might want to adjust fonts, spacing, etc.):

**html**:

```
<div class="prefix-wrapper">
  <span class="prefix">+91</span>
  <input type="text" value="">
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.prefix-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.prefix-wrapper .prefix {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 3px;
  left: 5px;
  color: #999;
}

input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/elatot/1/

Answer (score 0):

User still can click with a mouse or move the cursor and edit ***+91*** strings.

I would suggest that you bind `.keyup` and `.change` handlers to your input and check then if it contains your prefix(note that jQuery would be it much easier). Like this:

```
$('#your_input_id').on('keyup change', function() {
  if ( $(this).val().indexof('+91') != 0) $(this).val('+91');
});
```

Comment: It isnt working for me.. can anyone help me out for a code to disable backspce in chrome...

Comment: While a very consise anwer, and a much better implementation rather than trying to catch backspace/delete commands, the user does not seem to be using jQuery.

Comment: @RenéWolferink thanks. I just take jQuery for granted as it's cached pretty often and appears to be everywhere :)

Comment: Though I like to use jQuery as well, I think it's still good to at least know how it works underneath, also to keep in mind performace, especially on pages with many dom elements. And you'd be surprised how many command don't even use more lines of code in plain old javascript. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery:

**// HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class='phone' placeholder='+918888888888' value='' maxlength='13' />
```

**// jQuery code**

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var l = $('.phone').val().length;
    var elid = $(document.activeElement).hasClass('phone');
    if (e.keyCode === 8 && elid && l == 3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/dR3fx/)**

Answer (score 0):

A solution not using jQuery would be to hook up to the change/keyup events directly:

```
var checkPhone = function (e) {
    if (e.target.value.indexOf('+91') != 0) {
        e.target.value = '+91';
    }
}
var phoneElement = document.getElementById('phonen');
phoneElement.onchange = checkPhone;
phoneElement.onkeyup = checkPhone;
```